# How to insert nodes and values in binary search tree in java?

Tags: java

I am new to data structures and binary trees so I am a little bit lost . My problem is that how do we insert values in the tree itself ?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, you should mark it with the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check for this case explicitly.

**Update**

Also you'll need to add another `Add(int v)` method for public use (you can also make you current `Add(Node, int)` private).

```
public void Add(int v) {
    if (root == null) {
        // creating root node if it doesn't exist
        root = new Node();
        root.setValue(v);
    } else {
        // adding new element to tree
        Add(root, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: so in the Add method when i do     t.setRight(v); or t.setLeft(v);  i get an error saying that it can't be applied to given types because v is an int while setRight and setLeft only accept Node parammeters , so how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Got it. Your current `Add` method should be private (because it expose implementation detail `Node t` to public). And you should add new `Add(int v)` method. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new node like this:

```
Node n1 = new Node();
Node n2 = new Node();
n1.setValue(1);
n2.setValue(2);
n1.setRight(n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass `root` at the start.  You can just overload `Add`:

```
public void Add(int v) {
    Add(root, v);
}
```

And you'll need to special case the situation where `root == null`.